# SaltStack: How to depend on a ID in a sls file?

Tags: salt-stack

I want to depend on id `monitoring__user` of base.sls in optional.sls:

base.sls

```
monitoring__user:
  user.present:
    - name: {{...}}
```

optional.sls

```
monitoring_user_in_group_foo:
  group.present:
    - name: foo
    - addusers:
      - {{...}}
    - require:
       ###### how to depend on monitoring__user?
```

In the docs `require` looks like this `- pkg: vim`. Is there a way to only depend on the id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify either the `id` or the `name`. So your require would look like this:

```
- require:
  - user: monitoring__user
```

Comment: I just ask myself: Why is the `group:` before `monitoring_user_in_group_foo` needed? I though "monitoring_user_in_group_foo" is already an id (an **identifier**)

Comment: I thought about this again, and why it feels strange to me. I mostly do software development. If I look at "monitoring_user_in_group_foo" like a method in programming language, then it's strange that I need the leading "group:". The method name alone should be enough.

Comment: The method is inside the "group" module. Sort of a namespace.

Comment: the "group" module is from salt, or am I wrong? What does my name do inside a module from salt? I don't get it.

Comment: @Utah_Dave : I just edit the answer, please confirm whether it is due to typo.

Comment: @mootmoot I accepted your edit because you're correct that it wants to require on the user, but I modified it again because you can't use `- name` as part of the require.  You have to use `- user` because you're referring to the `user` state.   Thanks for helping clarify that!